# Non-Transactional SaveChanges with Breeze.js

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, transactions, breeze

Imagine you have a UI that consists of a list of items, each with a checkbox beside them. You can select multiple checkboxes and click a button to perform a bulk operation. The desire is to have as many of the rows be processed as possible. So if one row fails, the other selected rows should not roll back.

To do this with Breeze, would it make more sense to send multiple different saves, or is there a way to handle this scenario out of the box?

Sorry. I am new to Breeze, and have been looking through the docs, samples, and API and can't see any clear indication that this is possible. It appears that each call to SaveChanges is transactional. Or is a Named Save required to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What server technologies are you using?

Comment: When you say 'if one row fails' what are you referring to? Is this an expected scenario? It seems this is an XY problem?

Comment: Each item in the list has a next step that needs to be performed in a workflow. The user must select items to approve to continue to the next step in their workflow. The next step for each item may vary, and the outcome of each step may vary, but the outcome of one item shouldn't affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do a *non-transactional **batch save*** in Breeze. You're easiest course is to save each change individually. You can fire them off in parallel and wait for all to complete if that's important to you.

However, if you're game for some serious programming, it can be done. Here is the outline of the approach.

### How to write a non-transactional batch save in Breeze

The easy part is turning off the transaction on the server.

Take a look at the second parameter of `ContextProvider.SaveChanges`. It's a Breeze `TransactionSettings` object. If you "new" that up you'll get this

```
public TransactionSettings()
{
  this.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
  this.Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout;
  this.TransactionType = TransactionType.None;
}
```

You can change create one with any value you like but I'm calling attention to `TransactionType.None`.

Pass that in your call to `SaveChanges`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle, myTransactionSettings);
    }
```

I believe that will prevent the `EFContextProvider` from saving transactionally.

Now you have to fix things on the client side. I haven't turned off transactions so I'm not familiar with how errors are caught and transmitted to the client.

**The real challenge is on the client. You have to do something when the save fails partially. You have to help the Breeze `EntityManager` figure out which entities succeeded and which failed and process them appropriately ... or your entity cache will become unstable.**

You will have to write a [custom Data Service Adapter](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/dataserviceadapters) with some very tricky save processing logic. That is not easy!

I've done it in my Breeze Labs [*Abstract Rest Adapter*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.labs.dataservice.abstractrest.js) which is not documented and quite complex. You're welcome to read it and apply its reasoning to your own implementation of the "web api" Data Service Adapter. If you have budget, you might engage IdeaBlade professional services (makers of Breeze)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I don't think I'm quite game for writing a custom Data Service Adapter just yet. I'm still a noob with Breeze. So perhaps firing multiple requests will be better. Also, disabling Transactions altogether sounds like a bad idea because the inner workings of each item's processing should still be transactional. I've since learned that a large part of this processing is occurring in a stored proc and incorporates triggers as well. Oh goodie! Very unconventional, or perhaps just old school.

Comment: Ha! Oh what joy if the triggers update data for other entities that you're holding in client cache. You'll have to know about them somehow and refresh them too after save. Fun indeed!

Comment: When you say "refresh them", is it enough to just use EF to Refresh() them on the server, or do I have to manually set their entity state on the client somehow?

Comment: I meant "refresh them on the client". Let's say an update to 'A' triggers change to entity 'B'. Both 'A' and 'B' are in my client entity cache. After save, my cached 'A' matches the server 'A' but cached 'B' does not. My client probably should re-fresh 'B' (`EntityQuery.fromEntities([B]).using(manager).execute() ...`). This is something your client logic would have to know to do on its own.